# Intermittent non-selective query

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, selectivity

**tl;dr:** I believe that my particular query is selective, but Salesforce occasionally insists it isn't. Evidence follows. What am I missing?

====

Every now and again (7-8 occurrences since 2017-1-1), one particular query in one of my triggers is causing me issues, giving me the following error

> Asset: execution of AfterUpdate
>
> caused by: System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 200000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing.
>   Even if a field is indexed a filter might still not be selective when:
>
> 1. The filter value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains null)
> 2. Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that occurs many times)
>
> Trigger.Asset: line 20, column 1

The relevant section of trigger code is this

```
trigger Asset on Asset (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    List<Id> acctIds = new List<Id>();
    List<Asset> assetList = new List<Asset>();
    if (Trigger.isDelete) {
        assetList = Trigger.old;
    } else {
        assetList = Trigger.new;
    }
    for (Asset ass : assetList) {
        // Create list of accounts to update
        if (ass.AccountId <> null) acctIds.add(ass.AccountId);
    }

    if (acctIds.size() > 0) {
        List<Asset> allAssets = new List<Asset>([select Id,AccountId,Total_Amount__c,Product2Id,Product_Family__c,Allocated_NetEx_MRC_Total__c,NetEx_Rollup__c from Asset where AccountId in :acctIds and Status = 'Billing']);

        // The rest of the trigger below this point is omitted
        // The query on the line above is line 20 (or it would be, if I had included
        //   the 4 lines of comments at the very top of the trigger).
        // Don't let the 'allAssets' variable name fool you, it only queries 
        //   the Assets that have Status = 'Billing' and are related to an Account
        //   that at least one of the Asset records in Trigger.new is related to.
    }
}
```

Breaking out the problematic query for readability

```
SELECT Id, AccountId, Total_Amount__c, Product2Id, Product_Family__c,
    Allocated_NetEx_MRC_Total__c, NetEx_Rollup__c 
FROM Asset 
WHERE AccountId IN :acctIds AND Status = 'Billing'
```

### I can't for the life of me figure out why this is giving me a non-selective query error.

In the org where this is an issue, there are a total of 471,939 `Asset` records.

I've attempted to recreate the worst-case scenario that I believe this query should experience (given that it is part of a trigger). Using the following query, I was able to gather the list of the 200 `Account` records with the highest number of `Assets` being billed:

```
SELECT AccountId, COUNT(Id) FROM Asset WHERE Status = 'Billing' GROUP BY AccountId ORDER BY COUNT(Id) DESC LIMIT 200
```

I then plugged those 200 Account Ids into the problematic query. This simulates the case where each of the `Asset` records in the trigger context variables is for a separate `Account`, and each `Account` happens to be one of the 200 with the most `Asset` records being billed.

The query plan tool (through the developer console) gives me the following

[image: Result of query plan]

From [Query Plan Tool (How to & FAQ)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199003&type=1)

> Cost:
>
> The cost of the query compared to the Force.com Query Optimizer’s selectivity threshold. Values above 1 mean that the query won’t be selective.

In running my 'worst-case scenario' query via anonymous apex, the query runs just fine, and returns a total of 6037 records.

If I go further and query with the top 800 Accounts, I only end up with 11,311 records (by which time I'm firmly in the long-tail section of the distribution of `Assets`, each additional record having 7 or fewer `Assets` being billed).

I'm fairly sure that this particular query should check all the required boxes that would make it selective:

- Query cost is shown as 0.353152... in the worst case I can imagine happening
- Leading operation type is 'Index'
- `WHERE` clause uses a Standard index filter
- Number of records in the resultset is 6037 in my worst-case scenario
- The selectivity threshold for the first million records using a
  standard index is 30% (based on [Query Search Optimization cheat sheet](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/rel1/doc/en-us/static/pdf/salesforce_query_search_optimization_developer_cheatsheet.pdf)), 30% of 471,939 is 141,571
- No negative filters in the `WHERE` clause
- No nulls in the list of `Account` Ids

Am I missing something in working out the selectivity of my query?
Any ideas on why Salesforce occasionally says it isn't selective?

Comment: Do you perhaps have some sort of record skew? Meaning `Account` records which parent a large number of `Asset` records? Ah never mind, I see you did select those records with the most children.

Comment: @AdrianLarson depends on your definition of 'large'. The top 5 `Accounts` for number of `Asset` records being billed contain 961, 295, 192, 154, and 150. I haven't yet worked out how many total `Assets` those top 5 Accounts have.

Comment: Certainly doesn't account for the error with those figures. Have you opened a case with support? Maybe you would get that error if you ran this query as someone who lacks read permission on the `AccountId` field...

Comment: @AdrianLarson I have not, but removing the `Status = 'Billing'` from my 'top Accounts' query reveals there is a single `Account` with 89,802 `Assets` associated to it. That is most definitely a large number. I think skew is definitely the answer here. Now I just need to figure out how the hell a single `Account` has that many `Assets`...